# Программное управление настройками 2G интернета

Tags: java, android

Необходимо решение для программного изменения настройки 2G (мобильного интернета) true на false и наоборот. Долго рылся в официальной документации, нашел примеры для wi-fi и bluetooth:

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);  
  if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){  
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);  
  }else{  
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);  
  }
```

Только вот для мобильных данных такого менеджера не нашел(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы подключить/отключить 2G, нужно подключать/отключать опцию `Мобильные данные`

`private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}`

manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431963/how-to-disable-mobile-data-programmatically-for-my-app-only